# Which digital experience sites types are supported for mobile publisher?

Tags: experience-cloud, digital-experience, mobile-publisher

Which digital experience sites types are supported for mobile publisher?

Are both Aura and LWR types of Digital Experience sites supported for Mobile Publisher?

I cannot find information in this documentation https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.branded_apps_commun_faq.htm&type=5

Comment: The Experience Cloud group is very active, including from SFDC folks, so I would post there:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000001oDdCAI?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from SF on Experience Cloud group.

Copying it here.

> Aura is currently officially supported and GA. LWR support is in beta,
> but (Safe Harbor) we are working on it going GA sometime this year.